# Website opens with broken links without www in url but opens with it

Tags: iis

I have a website hosted on IIS that will load correctly with www.[sitename] but when I used just [sitename] in the url the site would still load but references to images and scripts are broken. I am able to ping both www.[sitename] and [sitename] and the same IP address are returned. The website is https so I'm guess it might be related to certificates, but is there anything else that might cause this?

Comment: Have you setup a binding for "[sitename]" in addition to "www.[sitename]"? If images and scripts cannot be loaded, check the console for error messages.